# Grails 1.2.0 not finding plugins in the default repository

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I do not know what changed in my environment, but all of a sudden I can not pull any plugins from the default repository.  I went through the _*.groovy scripts and nothing has changed in my grails home directory and it appears that the default repository url is set correctly (DEFAULT_PLUGIN_DIST = "http://plugins.grails.org").

I am assuming it is an environment setting that changed on me, because if I switch to an old version of grails that I have installed, 1.1.1 for example, list-plugins is returning a full list of plugins.

When I run grails list-plugins in my current 1.2.0 environment I get the following output:

Welcome to Grails 1.2.0 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /opt/grails-1.2.0

Base Directory: /Users/padraic/Projects/TestApplicationMachine
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 1633ms.
Running script /opt/grails-1.2.0/scripts/ListPlugins_.groovy
Environment set to development
Reading remote plugin list ...

### Plug-ins available in the core repository are listed below:

hibernate           <1.3.0.RC2>      --  Hibernate for Grails
tomcat              <1.3.0.RC2>      --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webflow             <1.3.0.RC2>      --  Spring Web Flow Plugin

Reading remote plugin list ...

### Plug-ins available in the default repository are listed below:

spock               <0.4-groovy-1.7-SNAPSHOT> --  Spock Integration - spockframework.org

### Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:

cloud-foundry       0.2              --  Cloud Foundry Plugin for Grails
hibernate           1.2.0            --  Hibernate for Grails
tomcat              1.2.0            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails

I find it very strange that it only finds the spock plugin.  It makes me thing that either a)it is going to the wrong repository or b)my version setting is incorrect.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Padraic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release of the Spock plugin corrupted the metadata XML file in the repository that contains information about all of the plugins. This has been fixed but you must have a cached copy locally. That will be in $HOME/.grails/1.2.0 - delete plugins-list-core.xml and plugins-list-default.xml and they will be re-downloaded when you run "grails list-plugins" or "grails install-plugin foo".